# why won't my program print the countOfX values?

Tags: c#, fizzbuzz

thanks for all your help in the last few q's! I think I've only got one issue remaining. For some reason it won't print the values of countOfX variables? As far as I can see it should work so there is obviously something im missing!

hopefully somebody can point me in the right direction at least. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
using System

namespace Part1Skeleton
{
class FizzBuzz
{
    int countOfFizz;
    int countOfBuzz;
    int countOfFizzBuzz;
    int countOfPrime;

    public static void Main()
    {
        int input = 1;
        //string enter;

        FizzBuzz fb = new FizzBuzz();
        fb.BeginTesting();

        while (input <= 20)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number: ");
            //enter = Console.ReadLine();
            //input = int.Parse(enter);

            fb.BeginTesting();
            fb.IsFizz(input);
            fb.IsBuzz(input);
            fb.IsFizzBuzz(input);
            fb.IsPrime(input);

            input++;
        }
        fb.TotalFizz();
        fb.TotalBuzz();
        fb.TotalFizzBuzz();
        fb.TotalPrime();
    }

    public bool IsFizz(int input)
    {
        if (input % 9 == 0 && input != 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Fizz");
            countOfFizz++;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public bool IsBuzz(int input)
    {
        if (input % 13 == 0 && input != 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Buzz");
            countOfBuzz++;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public bool IsFizzBuzz(int input)
    {
        if (input % 9 == 0 && input % 13 == 0 && input != 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("FizzBuzz");
            countOfFizzBuzz++;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public bool IsPrime(int input)
    {
        if (input == 0 || input == 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(input);
            return false;
        }
        else if (input % 9 == 0 || input % 13 == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 2; i < input; i++)
            {
                if (input % i == 0 && i != input)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(input);
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Prime");
        countOfPrime++;
        return true;
    }

    public void BeginTesting()
    {
        countOfFizz = 0;
        countOfBuzz = 0;
        countOfFizzBuzz = 0;
        countOfPrime = 0;
    }

    public int TotalFizz()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Number of Fizz: ");
        Console.Write(countOfFizz);
        return countOfFizz;
    }

    public int TotalBuzz()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Number of Buzz: ");
        Console.Write(countOfBuzz);
        return countOfBuzz;
    }

    public int TotalFizzBuzz()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Number of FizzBuzz: ");
        Console.Write(countOfFizzBuzz);
        return countOfFizzBuzz;
    }

    public int TotalPrime()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Number of Prime: ");
        Console.Write(countOfPrime);
        return countOfPrime;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: What is the expected output ? why are some of the lines are commented out ?

Comment: You're not calling the Total methods on the same instances of the FizzBuzz class that you've done any work on! Why are you creating so many - what was your intention? Why not just make one at the start and call all of the methods on that?

Comment: agreed with @Rup why are you creating so many object and then calling each on method on diff objects ?

Comment: @Ofiris the lines are commented out because eventually it will have an input of random numbers to check so i wanted a place for them to be entered. but for purposes of testing im using the first 20 numbers.

Comment: @EmmadKareem i used countOfX to stand for countOfFizz etc...

Answer (score 1):

Why are you creating new instances of FizzBuzz in while loop? 
Just create a single instance before the start of while loop and use it throughout your program.

Try this main code

```
public static void Main()
    {
        int input = 1;
        //string enter;

       FizzBuzz fb = new FizzBuzz(); // create a single instance
       fb.BeginTesting(); // start testing

        while (input <= 20)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number: ");
            //enter = Console.ReadLine();
            //input = int.Parse(enter);
            fb.IsFizz(input);
            fb.IsBuzz(input);
            fb.IsFizzBuzz(input);                
            fb.IsPrime(input);

            input++;
        }

        fb.TotalFizz();            
        fb.TotalBuzz();            
        fb.TotalFizzBuzz();            
        fb.TotalPrime();
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the advice! i've changed it now, I havent even looked at that part of the code yet really. It looks a lot better now. Its still not printing a count though? any ideas.

Comment: In your while loop you have this code "fb.BeginTesting();", which will reset the counting to 0. Remove this line and try again.

Comment: works perfectly! you have no idea how grateful i am right now! and also how much of an idiot i feel. thanks dude!